# Send a variable on the heap to another thread

Tags: c++, windows, class, heap-memory, memory-address

I have a strange problem in C++. An address of a Boolean gets "destroyed" but it doesn't get touched. I know that there are better ways to accomplish what I try to do, but I want to know what I do wrong.

I have a main class; this main class contains a vector of another class. There is a strange problem when a new instance gets created of this object.

This is how my code works:

There will start a thread when the constructor gets called of the “2nd” object. This thread gets as Parameter a struct. This is the struct:

```
struct KeyPressData
{
    vector<bool> *AutoPressStatus;
    vector<int> *AutoPressTime;
    bool * Destroy;
    bool * Ready;
};
```

The struct gets filled in the constructor:

```
MultiBoxClient::MultiBoxClient()
{
    //init data
    DestroyThread = new bool;
    ReadyThread = new bool;
    AutoThreadData = new KeyPressData;  

    //Reseting data
    *DestroyThread = false;
    *ReadyThread = false;   

    //KeyPressData configurating
    AutoThreadData->AutoPressStatus = &AutoPressStatus;
    AutoThreadData->AutoPressTime = &AutoPressTime;
    AutoThreadData->Destroy = DestroyThread;
    AutoThreadData->Ready = ReadyThread;

    //Start the keypress thread
    CreateThread(NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)AutoKeyThread,AutoThreadData,NULL,NULL); 
}
```

This is the defenition of MultiBoxClient:

```
class MultiBoxClient
{
    private:
        HWND ClientHandle;                                  
        vector<bool> KeyPresses;                                

        vector<bool> AutoPressStatus;                           
        vector<int> AutoPressTime;                              

        KeyPressData * AutoThreadData;                          

        bool * DestroyThread;                                       
        bool * ReadyThread;                                     

    public:
        MultiBoxClient();
        MultiBoxClient(HWND Handle);                            
        ~MultiBoxClient();                                      

        void EditClient(HWND Handle);                           

        void SendKeypress(vector<bool> KeyStatus);              
        void SendKeyCombination(unsigned int id);               
        void AutoCast(int Key,unsigned int Time,bool status);   

        bool IsAlive();                                         

};
```

MultiBoxClient is created this way:

```
int main()
{
    MultiboxControler * MainControler = new MultiboxControler;

    while(true)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    delete MainControler;

    return false;
}
```

As long as the constructor is running will the program run fine. But when the constructor closes the address of the `AutoThreadData->Destroy` will get corrupted. The program will crash when I call the value of the pointer.

```
void WINAPI AutoKeyThread(void * ThreadData)
{

    KeyPressData * AutoThreadData = (KeyPressData*)ThreadData;

    while(true)
    {   
        if(*AutoThreadData->Destroy == true)    //CRASH
        {
            *AutoThreadData->Ready = true;
            return;
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

What did I test:

I logged the address of the AutoThreadData and the `AutoThreadData->Destroy` when the constrcutor is running and clossed; the `AutoThreadData` address is equal to `AutoThreadData` when the constructor is closed. So there is no problem here.

The address of `AutoThreadData->Destroy` gets destroyed when the constructor is closed. But how can this happen? The Boolean is on the heap and the `KeyPressData` struct (AutoThreadData) is on the heap.

```
Destroy before: 00A85328
Destroy after: FEEEFEEE
```

Can someone maby explain why this crash?

I know that I can send a pointer to my class to the thread. But I want to know what goes wrong here. That way I can learn from my mistakes.

Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Can you add the definition of MultiBoxClient to the code sample?  Also, can you add the code where MultiBoxClient() is constructed?

Comment: Thanks, I add the definition and the way it is constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you made a mistake with the vector, use a class pointer, instead of the class itself, like this:

```
vector<class*> //instead of vector<class>
```

Comment: What class are you referring to?  I only see vectors of `bool` and `int`

Comment: He pointed to: "this main class contains a vector of another class." and that was indeed my problem. Thanks every one for helping me.

Comment: @user1201889 - I don't see how this answer helped you, as there is no access of vector objects in the code of the question (only taking address of vectors and asigning it), so clearly, changing the type of the vectors won't make a difference.  So either you did not post the relevant part of the code (and than how is anybody else going to guess?) or if you did, please let me know what you have changed in the question's code to make it work based on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

`0xFEEEFEEE` is an indication of freed memory. That is, you `AutoThreadData` was deleted, and it was not on your worker thread which is in endless loop. So, it has to be your main thread and perhaps destructor, which you did not show.

Whereever you destroy/free your `KeyPressData` instance, comment this out or set a breakpoint there to find out where it is taking place.

Comment: The problem is indeed that the destructor gets called when the instance is created. But I did’t call it. I add the main thread to the post.

Comment: @user1201889: The whole point of stack-based lifetime is that the destructor is automatically called for you when the scope ends.

Comment: True, but the destructor also gets called when I make the object on the heap.

Comment: Don't guess - set a breakpoint in destructor and once it is hit check call stack to see where it is called from. There is no way you have it called without a reason.